# Adding USER to dockerfile makes me lose access to endpoints

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

I'm having issues with adding and running my app from a non-root user.
I have a dockerfile with that runs a simple FastAPI app. Everything works fine and I can call the endpoints and I get the desired results (just a simple string).

As soon I add the following lines I stop being able to access the endpoints:

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash admin

RUN chown -R admin:admin /var/lib/nginx /var/log/nginx /etc/nginx /app
USER admin
```

This is the full docker with the previous lines added:

```
# Start with a lightweight base image
FROM python:3.11.2-slim AS base

# Create a virtual environment for app
RUN python -m venv /venv

# Set the virtual environment as the default Python environment
ENV PATH="/venv/bin:$PATH"

# Copy only necessary files
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt ./
COPY src ./src
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

#Next stage
FROM python:3.11.2 AS final

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash admin

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get install -y nginx

# Copy the virtual environment from the base image
COPY --from=base /venv /venv
# Set the virtual environment as the default Python environment
ENV PATH="/venv/bin:$PATH"

# Copy only necessary files
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=base /app .

COPY configs/docker-starter.sh docker-starter.sh
# Copy Nginx configuration file
COPY configs/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN chown -R admin:admin /var/lib/nginx /var/log/nginx /etc/nginx /app
USER admin

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "docker-starter.sh"]
```

nginx seems to start fine as stated in the console log `Starting nginx: nginx.`

my docker-starter.sh contains:

```
service nginx start & gunicorn -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 src.main:app
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: shouldn't this line give permissions to it?
RUN chown -R admin:admin /var/lib/nginx /var/log/nginx /etc/nginx /app

Ye. I edited the original post and included the docker-starter.sh info

Comment: What process is running as PID 1 in this container?

Comment: `RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt` This line is placed after `COPY src ./src`, which is going to defeat layer caching, and require that every change to your app re-download your requirements.

Comment: @Mushroomator I'm confused by what you said. 
`WORKDIR /app`
`COPY --from=base /app .`

followed by `RUN chown -R admin:admin /app` shouldn't this grant permissions to access the app (which is where it's placed)?

Comment: Nevermind. Missed the `/app` at the end, sorry.

Comment: @NickODell as for PID 1 `admin        1  0.0  0.0   2060   488 ?        Ss   16:22   0:00 sh docker-starter.sh`

Comment: You're not using systemd or supervisord, or something like that? What is `service nginx start` doing?

Comment: @NickODell it starts nginx

Comment: @NickODell after running the different images I get different results when inspecting PID.
Without USER:
`root 21  0.0  0.0   8192   804 ?    Ss  16:47  0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/ngin`  
`nobody 22  0.0  0.0   8564  2828 ?  S  16:47   0:00 nginx: worker process`

this does not appear when running with USER

Comment: Are you using systemd or supervisord, or something like that?

Comment: @NickODell no I'm not

Comment: Generally containers should do one thing. I.E you would have a continer for fastapi and a container for nginx, generally you wouldnt house both in the same container.